# How can you generically transform a function's return type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a REST API library that returns a `Promise<string>` for all of its functions.  I would like to write a generic wrapper function to wrap the API function, parse the JSON, and return the data typed with the template parameter.

I have something that basically works, but because of https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16597 I haven't managed to do it without currying:

```
type Args<F> = F extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never

export function apiCall<T>() {
  return function<F extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<string>>(fn: F) {
    return function(...args: Args<F>): Promise<T> {
      return fn(...args).then(JSON.parse)
    }
  }
}
```

You then create the wrapper function like this:

```
const wrapper = apiCall<ReturnType>()(apiFunction)
```

This seems like it ought to be a one-liner.  I really don't like adding an extra function call just to satisfy the type system.  The difficulty here is keeping the same parameter types but changing the return type.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately currently you need to use the extra function approach. Typescript does not allow partial argument inference. You can either let the compiler infer types or you can specify them, but not a combination of the two (we can omit type parameters that have default values but that does not help us as the default will be used if we specify one parameter and we would need inference to occur for such parameters as well)

Fortunately you will not need to wait long for this feature. Typescript 3.2 will add support for this as stated in this [ticket](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26349). If implemented as currently stated you will be able to write

```
const wrapper = apiCall<ReturnType, *>(apiFunction)
```

**Note**: This feature has slipped at least once, we will see if it makes in it in 3.2 (slated for November 2018)

Comment: In my case I needed to bind the function - the types of the arguments seem to get erased when you call `bind`.  Still can be worked around, but makes things uglier.

Comment: @KeithLayne That is a general problem with bind and will be fixed in 3.2 with Strict bind, call, and apply methods on functions. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27028

Comment: The interface feels pretty bad no matter whether I call `bind` at the call site or pass the object to the function.  It doesn't help that in my case the library I'm wrapping names everything in an overly verbose way.  I think the most ergonomic solution (that I can immediately think of) would look like `wrap<T>(obj, 'function')` where the second arg is typechecked against the keys that match a certain function signature, and then all the types magically just worked.  Maybe in TS 7.

Comment: @KeithLayne the key part can be done .. if you post a fuller example of what you are trying to do maybe we can work something out